# Pandas: downsample and sum without filling spaces (or leaving `NaN`s)

Tags: python, pandas

Having this time series:

```
>>> from pandas import date_range
>>> from pandas import Series
>>> dates = date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10', freq='D')[[0, 4, 5, 8]]
>>> dates
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-09'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> series = Series(index=dates, data=[0., 1., 2., 3.])
>>> series
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-05    1.0
2019-01-06    2.0
2019-01-09    3.0
dtype: int64
```

I can resample with Pandas to `'2D'` and get:

```
series.resample('2D').sum()
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-03    0.0
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-07    0.0
2019-01-09    3.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: int64
```

However, I would like to get:

```
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-09    3.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: int64
```

Or at least (so that I can drop the `NaN`s):

```
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-03    Nan
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-07    Nan
2019-01-09    3.0
Freq: 2D, dtype: int64
```

### Notes

- Using latest Pandas version (0.24)
- Would like to be able to use the `'2D'` syntax (or `'W'` or `'3H'` or whatever...) and let Pandas care about the grouping/resampling

This looks dirty and inefficient. Hopefully someone comes up with a better alternative. :-D

```
>>> resampled = series.resample('2D')
>>> (resampled.mean() * resampled.count()).dropna()
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-09    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the named argument `min_count`:

```
>>> series.resample('2D').sum(min_count=1).dropna()
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-09    3.0
```

Performance comparison with other methods, from faster to slower (run your own tests, as it may depend on your architecture, platform, environment...):

```
In [38]: %timeit resampled.sum(min_count=1).dropna()                            
588 µs ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit (resampled.mean() * resampled.count()).dropna()                
622 µs ± 3.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [40]: %timeit resampled.sum()[resampled.count() != 0].copy()                 
960 µs ± 1.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about this argument !

Comment: @vlemaistre Me neither! xD

Answer (score 1):

It would be clearer to use `resampled.count()` as a condition after using sum like this :

```
resampled = series.resample('2D')
resampled.sum()[resampled.count() != 0]
```

Out :

```
2019-01-01    0.0
2019-01-05    3.0
2019-01-09    3.0
dtype: float64
```

On my computer this method is 22% faster (5.52ms vs 7.15ms).

Comment: It is indeed clearer. Still looks a bit dirty to me (i.e.: very similar to my approach), so I will wait a bit in case someone comes-up with something better/different before accepting.

Comment: Actually, I came-up with a new answer with a better-looking and faster approach. Will still wait before accepting in case there is something even better.